# How to dynamically create parameterized pods in kubernetes

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes, azure-webjobs, azure-aks

I have a web front end processing webhooks and sending messages to a backend worker. These messages belong to different organizations, each message has the following format:

```
class Message{
   int OrganizationId {get;set;}
   string Payload {get;set;}
}
```

Today, the processing backend is implemented as an Azure Webjob. The webjob is simple console application intercepting the messages sent from the front end. The console application lists all organizations pending in the queue and creates a thread for each one so the messages can be processed in parallel for each organization.

Azure Webjobs do unfortunately not scale that well (the reasons are along the same lines covered in this [article](https://blog.dirk-eisenberg.de/2018/07/17/kubernetes-vs-azure-app-services-webjobs-why-i-switched/)). We are considering to move the background processing tasks to Kubernetes. Ideally, each organization messages should be processed in a container. These containers will be grouped in groups of 5 in each pod.

While the pod configuration is simple, we can't figure out a way to automatically and continuously discover organizations in the message queue and fire off a container with the organization ID as a parameter.

Note: The current implementation does not allow us to split each organization messages into a separate queue as there can be thousands of organizations pumping messages to the queue at the same time.

Comment: If you already have logic to discover the organization IDs, then running that in a Pod inside the cluster allows you to use the Pod's Service Account Token to create new Pods -- almost like your own kubernetes controller. One would need careful consideration for what happens if a container falls over, however, but that isn't what you asked

Comment: Have you already considered [knative](https://knative.dev/docs/)? It seems to be what all the cool kids are using nowadays

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I thought of that too (firing off pods manually) but that apparently defeats the purpose as those pods should be controlled via K8 APIs via a custom controller or something along the lines.

Comment: defeats the purpose of what? Every pod in Kubernetes is launched by a controller based on some event, so I don't know why your external message queue would be any different except there isn't an existing controller for that metric. But as you wish